# Wygwam 3.0.2 PHP Error in EE 2.5.5

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

On a number of EE 2.5.5 sites with Wygwam 3.0.2, I'm getting this PHP error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered  
Severity: Notice  
Message: Undefined index: defer  
Filename: wygwam/ft.wygwam.php  
Line Number: 443
```

The error does not seem to happen on EE 2.6.
PHP version is 5.3.2

Comment: Did you recently update Wygwam from a version that was older than Wygwam 2.1.1? Can you try re-saving your Wygwam fields?

Comment: No I was on the latest version prior to 3.0.2. Resaving the fields did get rid of the error message though. Thanks.

Comment: I had this same issue with EE 2.5.5 after updating Wygwam to 3.2
Re-saving the Wygwam field fixed the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 5):

Having recently upgraded an EE v1.6.8 site to v2.6.1, I had to re-save each of the Wygwam fields to fix the "defer" PHP notice.

http://website.com/manage.php?D=cp&C=admin_content&M=field_group_management

Comment: Just had the exact same issue in EE 2.5.5 and Wygwam 3.1.2. Re-saving the fields fixed it for me too, so thanks for the answer, Jarrett.